# Cannot assign parent categories on post save

Tags: php, wordpress

I've pulled together this script from  a few posts on here.

I have a post type of `artwork`
I have a taxonomy of `art_type`

What I'm looking to do is assign the parent categories if a child category is selected and also keep that child category selected.

Can anyone work out why all this does is completely remove all categories on save. Bit of a headscratcher for me.

```
add_action('save_post', function ($post_id, $post) {
    if (isset($post) && $post->post_type !== 'artwork') {
        return $post_id;
    }

    $terms = wp_get_post_terms($post_id, 'art_type');

    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        while ($term->parent !== 0 && !has_term($term->parent, 'art_type', $post)) {
            wp_set_object_terms($post_id, array($term->parent), 'art_type', true);
            $term = get_term($term->parent, 'art_type');
        }
    }
}, 10, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the taxonomies were being set in ACF fields as well as the standard sidebar widget and it looks as though ACF takes priority over the standard WP call

Code above works perfectly otherwise.